# Update settings of static tabs

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a custom App in Teams, with a static tab
configuration snippet from manifest.json:

```
"staticTabs": [
    {
        "entityId": "12345",
        "name": "Tab name",
        "contentUrl": "https://myweb.com/index.html",
        "scopes": [ "personal" ]
    }
],
```

Is it possible to change the settings afterwards, using the javascript sdk?
in the channel/group (configurable) tabs it's a piece of cake with the  `microsoftTeams.setSettings({contentUrl: 'new-conten-url'})`. However, this approach is not working with the static tabs. Is there any trick how to make it working in the static tabs as well?

I'd like to add a query param to the `contentUrl`.

**Why? force refresh!**

when there is a new version of the app on my site `https://myweb.com/`, even with a new manifest, MS Teams stubbornly serving the previous, cached version. I'm able to detect the msteams app is running against out-dated version, I can replace the current url with a new one (e.g with a timestamp in url) but I'd like to save it to the settings, so when the user come back later, he'd get the "fresh" link and no more reloading wouldn't be necessary

Comment: Updating the content URL dynamically is not supported currently. You can update the manifest with latest URL and sideload it again

Comment: Thank you, are there any plans to support this?

Comment: Currently, we do not have any plans for this.